# RStudio project name

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to force RStudio to use the project (.Rproj) name instead of the directory that the project resides in?

For example, I have a project that I've named shapefiles.Rproj, but it resides inside of the "data" directory, and therefore, the name at the top of the taskbar shows as "data", but I'd like to show as "shapefiles".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a long-standing request that's not yet implemented. See
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1909.